# How do I extract pairs of values from matrix cells?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, compare, sequence

I have two matrices, from which I want to extract all unique pairs of values in corresponding cells. That is, I want to pair the value from cell [1,1] in the first matrix with the cell [1,1] in the second matrix and then reduce that list of pairs to include only the unique pairs. How do I do this?

Here are sample versions of the matrices

```
     V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6 
[1,] "w" "o" "r" "d" NA  NA 
[2,] "p" "o" "r" "c" NA  NA 
[3,] "v" "i" "n" NA  NA  NA 
[4,] "s" "e" "l" NA  NA  NA 
[5,] "p" "i" "e" "d" NA  NA 
[6,] "p" "i" "e" "r" "r" "e"

      V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6 
[1,] "h" "a" "e" "d" "a" NA 
[2,] "p" "o" "r" "c" "u" "s"
[3,] "v" "i" "n" "u" "m" NA 
[4,] "s" "a" "l" NA  NA  NA 
[5,] "p" "e" "s" NA  NA  NA 
[6,] "p" "e" "t" "r" "u" "s"
```

Comment: and what is the desired outcome from running your algorithm on the above? start by m1 == m2 where m1 and m2 are your matrices

Comment: The desired outcome is pairs derived from the corresponding cells, ("w", "h") from cell 1,1 of each matrix. I want to know all the unique pairs between two matrices for all rows and columns.

Comment: actually write down in the post how you want your results to look like. Your description can be hard to understand for someone like me who is not close to the problem.

Comment: try which(m1 == m2)

Comment: also make your post contain code that someone can actually run would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't we just do:

```
unique( paste(m1, m2) )
```

Testing:

```
>  m1 <- scan(what="") 
1:  "w" "o" "r" "d" NA  NA 
7:  "p" "o" "r" "c" NA  NA 
13:  "v" "i" "n" NA  NA  NA 
19:  "s" "e" "l" NA  NA  NA 
25:  "p" "i" "e" "d" NA  NA 
31:  "p" "i" "e" "r" "r" "e"
37: 
Read 36 items
>   m2 <- scan(what="")
1:  "h" "a" "e" "d" "a" NA 
7:  "p" "o" "r" "c" "u" "s"
13:  "v" "i" "n" "u" "m" NA 
19:  "s" "a" "l" NA  NA  NA 
25:  "p" "e" "s" NA  NA  NA 
31:  "p" "e" "t" "r" "u" "s"
37: 
Read 36 items
> unique( paste(m1, m2) )
 [1] "w h"   "o a"   "r e"   "d d"   "NA a"  "NA NA" "p p"   "o o"   "r r"   "c c"   "NA u" 
[12] "NA s"  "v v"   "i i"   "n n"   "NA m"  "s s"   "e a"   "l l"   "i e"   "e s"   "d NA" 
[23] "e t"   "r u"
```